# Stacking Enhancement Bonuses

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Do enhancement bonuses to ability scores stack?

Such as from a Belt of Giant Strength and from the spell Bull's Strength?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

No enhancement bonuses [stack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#stacking). No bonuses of the same type stack, except for dodge and circumstance bonuses (but good luck getting those to raise your Strength).

> In most cases, modifiers to a given check or roll stack (combine for a cumulative effect) if they come from different sources and have different types (or no type at all), but **do not stack if they have the same type** or come from the same source (such as the same spell cast twice in succession).

The entire point of a bonus type is that bonuses of the same type do not stack.

Answer (score 2):

**No** unless the description of the effect granting the bonus states otherwise.

> Multiple enhancement bonuses on the same object (in the case of armor and weapons), creature (in the case of natural armor), or ability score do not stack. Only the highest enhancement bonus applies.

[link](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#enhancementBonus)

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Like (almost) all typed bonuses, only the highest bonus takes effect.

Dodge bonuses are an exception, in that they always stack.

Some Circumstances bonuses can stack.

Aside from these, exceptions to the rules will be called out by whatever provides the bonus.

Bonus Types rules are on DMG 3.5, page 21.